# html form does not work inside fieldsets

Tags: php, html

I have a field set and inside it i have a form . it does not work . i mean to say . when i see the tags using firebug , the form tags will not be there at all..how do u i get over it.

this is how the code goes...its a php code..

```
<div id="dialog-form_surg_couns" title=" Surgical Counselling">

<?php
$surgCount = 0;
foreach($this->surgery as $surgery) {
$surgCount++;
$newId = str_replace(' ','',$surgery->getSurgeryname());
?>
    <div class='fieldreq1Pct'>
      <div class='fieldItemLabel'>
                <label for=''><?php echo $surgery->getSurgeryname() ?></label>
      </div>
        <div class='fieldItemValue'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='surg_couns_tests' id="<?php echo $newId ?>" name='surg_couns_tests' value="<?php echo $surgery->getSurgeryname() ?>" <?php echo (($showValue &&  strstr($visitRecord->getSurgcounstests(),$surgery->getSurgeryname())) ? 'checked' : "" ); ?> onClick="javascript:showBlock(this.id);">
         </div>
    </div>
<?php
if(($surgCount % 3) == 0)
{
?>
                <div class='clear'></div>
<?php
}
}
?>
                <div class='clear'></div>
<hr/>
<?php
foreach($this->surgery as $surgery) {
$newId = str_replace(' ','',$surgery->getSurgeryname());
$fieldCount = 0;
?>
<div id='<?php echo $newId ?>_block' style='display:none;' class='check_block'>
<form method='POST' action ='' id ='<?php echo $newId ?>_form'>
<table border='0' class='surg_table'>
<?php
foreach($this->surgeryTemplate as $surgerytemplate) {
if($surgery->getSurgeryid() == $surgerytemplate->getSurgeryid())
{
$fieldCount++;
$fieldName      = 'field'.$fieldCount;
$fieldId        = $surgerytemplate->getFieldid();
if($surgerytemplate->getRequired() == 'Y')
{
 $required = 'required';
}
else
{
 $required = '';
}
if($surgerytemplate->getType() == 'AN')
{
 $validation = 'alpha';
}
else
{
 $validation = '';
}

?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $surgerytemplate->getFieldname(); ?>
</td>
<td>
<?php
if($surgerytemplate->getType() == 'B')
{
echo '<input type=\'radio\' name=\''.$fieldName.'\' value=\'Yes\'>Yes';
echo '<input type=\'radio\' name=\''.$fieldName.'\' value=\'No\'>No';
}
else
{
echo '<input type=\'text\' name=\''.$fieldName.'\' id=\''.$fieldName.'\' class=\''.$required.'  '.$validation.'\' onblur="checkValid(this.id)"><div id=\''.$fieldName.'error\'></div>';
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
</table>
 <center><input type='button' name='submit' value='submit' onclick='javascript:submitSurgeryForm("<?php echo $newId ?>")'></center>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: The way you're using fieldsets is wrong, because fieldsets are meant to be used INSIDE the form, for logical grouping of form elements, not the other way around.

Comment: @FreekOne  - i have changed my code...but the form tage is coming only for the second loop. 1st loop the form tag is not coming..any problem in code?

Comment: this is why people hate php code. Please indent, comment and get your HTML out of your logic if at all possible. http://www.dagbladet.no/development/phpcodingstandard/

Comment: I very much agree with Gabriel. If you don't mind your source code looking like that, so be it, but if you're asking for help don't force whomever is helping you to clean and indent the code for you as it is not their job, and many will simply turn away and choose not to help. That being said, after I read your code a couple of times (pretty hard to follow), I couldn't find any reason why the form tag would only show up after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `form` tag inside another form. The following HTML is invalid:

```
 <form>
   <fieldset>
     <form>
       <input>
     </form>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

The browser will silently ignore the second form, and instead will interpret your page as:

```
 <form>
   <fieldset>
     <input>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: after reading the given code a few times, I'm pretty sure it doesn't output nested forms. The first `foreach` can be ignored, the second one outputs a form for each iteration, and the third one -- wich is nested in the second one -- will output the form elements.

Comment: @FreekOne: Yes, you're right. However, the example code does not include the mentioned fieldset, so I'm assuming that the fieldset - and the form inside which it is - was omitted from the example code.

Comment: If you follow the comments on the initial question, I have already suggested that this will not work and the code you see now is an updated version of the initial one.